# how to pass single column as header inside dataframe : i am facing error : Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a below header with one column in string format

```
col = cur.execute("select col_name from ColTable")
kp = []
for ak in col:
    column_name = str(ak[1]).replace("().","")
    for k in column_name.split():
        kp.append(k)

header = str(kp)[1:-1]

header = eval(header)


header = 'EmployeeId'

header = eval(header)

df = pd.dataframe(columns=header)
```

I am getting

> TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind,
>   "('EmployeeId')" was passed

I also tried `columns=list(header)` , it is creating issue and header is getting divided as below

```
'E','m','p','l','e'...
```

Comment: `df = pd.dataframe(columns=[header]) `

Comment: your eval statement looks like it's going to raise some error unless there is additional context you're not showing. I'm not sure why you think you need that line, but you almost certainly do not.

Comment: @DavidZemens. I am getting KeyError: "['EmployeeId'] not in index"

Comment: No you're not. You're absolutely not getting that error from the pd.DataFrame constructor. Please edit your quesiton to show the code you're actually using as an [mcve], along with the full stack trace.

Comment: @DavidZemens. I have added my complete code.

Comment: The code youve added above provides zero additional information here. It doesn't do anything, as you overwrite `header` with a string literal `"EmployeeID"`. If you do `pd.DataFrame(columns=[header])` it will not have the error.

Comment: As noted, `eval(header)` will likely raise a NameError unless you've defined a variable `EmployeeID` elsewhere in scope.

Comment: @DavidZemens. When i used pd.DataFrame(columns=[header]) i am getting [EmployeeId] but we required format as ['EmployeeId']

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `EmployeeID` and `"EmployeeID"`?  Probably somewhere, you have instantiated a variable `EmployeeID`. When you (for unknown reason) `eval` the string, it returns the variable. So that is your likely disconnect. Again. SHOW ALL OF YOUR CODE. I promise, if you do `pd.DataFrame(["EmployeeID"])` you will not get the error. If `header` contains a *string* rather than another name, you wll not get the error. But since you are wrongly using `eval`, that seems to be your problem.